# tomcat deploy plugin with child war projects

Tags: maven, maven-tomcat-plugin, maven-war-plugin

i have main project  with 3 war modules i need to deploy the main war file using tomcat-maven-plugin

```
Parent
   - Main War Project child of Parent(Has dependecy of 3 war modules)
   - war module child of parent
   - war module child of parent
   - war module child of parent
```

if i add the plugin in parent project each war module is tring to deploy, which is not required

But i need to deploy only when the maven-war-plugin do "Webapp assembled" of the main war project

i add the plugin to main war project pom, which is not working. and gives

> No plugin found for prefix 'tomcat7' in the current project and in the
>   plugin groups

Comment: please write comment before down vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have added the

> tomcat7-plugin

in the Main War Project with lifecyle config when deploy happen i have added the goal to run

> tomcat7:deploy

its working fine.